# Is their any size or number limit if deleting multiple items with same partition key

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am planning to use deleteAllItemsByPartitionKey method for deleting documents with same partition key. The number of documents will be more than 1k and size can also be more than 2MB. Is their any such limit with method deleteAllItemsByPartitionKey like it is with CosmosBatch .

Answer (score 1):

There's no such limit.

Using `CosmosBatch`, you can send data within the request and must adhere to a size limit for that request. The `DeleteAllItemsByPartitionKey` feature only sends the partition key so even with the largest possible partition there's hardly any data send in the request. The server will then initiate the process of deleting all items in the background without requiring any additional input.

Comment: Documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-delete-by-partition-key?tabs=dotnet-example